# Code::Blocks, WinAPI, компиляция в режиме Unicode и ANSI

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, charset

Подскажите, что нужно сделать в **Code::Blocks**, чтобы **WinAPI** макросы разворачивались в **Unicode** версию?

Не знаю, как сформулировать этот вопрос яснее.

Например, по умолчанию в **Code::Blocks** макрос **CreateFile()** разворачивается в вызов функции **CreateFileA()**, а синоним **TCHAR** задан для **char**.

В **Visual Studio** в настройках проекта есть пункт, кажется, он называется **набор символов** или **char set**, который отвечает за используемый набор символов.

Может, нужно руками задать макроконстанту в настройках проекта? Или как?

Comment: эти `/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" `

Comment: @KoVadim, куда это прописывать? Что-то я такого не встречал. Я пытаюсь использовать **wmain()** и параметр компиляции **-municode**, но **MinGW w64** не хочет принимать **wmain()**.

Comment: это параметры компилятору. Через `-m` они не задаются. Для MinGW скорее всего они будут записываться как `-D_UNICODE -DUNICODE`

Comment: Что-то не помогает...

Comment: [wWinmain, Unicode, and Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11706847)